# Object has no method 'replace'

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm try to run this function, which grabs all the checked checkbox values in to a comma separated string, and converts `","` in to `", "`, so it reads better. The problem is I'm getting a strange error:

```
$('.name_boxes').live('click', function() {
    var all_boxes = $('.name_boxes');
    var all_boxes_values = []
    for (var i = 0; i < all_boxes.length; i++) {
        if (all_boxes[i].checked) {
            all_boxes_values.push(all_boxes[i].value)
        }
    }
    var all_boxes_values_clean = all_boxes_values.replace(/,/g,", ");
    alert(all_boxes_values_clean);
});
```

The console error says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object Aaron Ramsey,Aaron Renfree has no method 'replace'.

I'm not getting the alert box.

This is a bit beyond me, can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `replace`-method can only use for strings, not for `Array`-object. Create a loop for replacing actual values in `all_boxes_values`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although `alert(some_array)` prints a string representation of the array, the array itself is not a string. Thus, it does not have `.replace`. `alert` is forced to convert it into a string because the alert box can only show characters.

You can simply join using a custom separator, though. `join` is a function of arrays:

```
var all_boxes_values_clean = all_boxes_values.join(", ");
```

As a side note, I recommend `console.log` over `alert` because it:

1. shows the actual object/array instead of a string representation (especially useful with objects instead of the useless `[object Object]` you receive with `alert`)
2. frees you from closing the popup each time
3. keeps track of other logs so that you have an actual log of logs

Comment: Hi @pimvdb, 
Could you pleaz answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653866/has-no-method-replace-with-jquery-flot-tooltip-js
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`all_boxes_values` is an array, not a strings and thus it has no `replace` method.

Try

```
var all_boxes_values_clean = all_boxes_values.join(", ");
```

If you insist on performing regular expressions, convert an array to string first: `all_boxes_values.toString()`.